# Mysql get a row depending of different selects

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 4 tables: one called games that include all games of my application, another table rapresents "steps" of game (or levels) where player can join, then users table, because a user create a player for each game that he join

So tables are games, steps, players and users. This is games table:

```
game_id  game_name
1        game1
2        game2
```

This is steps table (column tickets is a counter of a determinate action, and step_num is a column for determinate default step):

```
step_id  step_tickets  step_game  step_num
1        384           1          1
2        742           1          2
3        21            2          1
```

And this is players table

```
player_id  player_step  player_user
1          2            1
```

Also users table, that have an id and some other info that we don't need now.

I would like to obtain step_tickets from steps table depending of given user and game.
For example if i give user 1 and game 1, I want to get row 2 of steps table, because user 1 has player 1, that joined in step 2.
If I give user 2 and game 1, user hasn't a player, so by default I want row 1.

I use Mysql version 5.6

I tried with this code but nothing... can anyone help me? Thank you in advance and make me know if you need other info.

```
SELECT 
    p.tickets AS mytickets, 
FROM games 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT 
        IF(t.step_tickets IS NULL, d.step_tickets, t.step_tickets) AS tickets,
        IF(t.step_game IS NULL, d.step_game, t.step_game) AS step_game,
        IF(t.step_id IS NULL, d.step_id, t.step_id) AS step_id
    FROM steps
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT 
            `step_tickets`, 
            `step_game`, 
            `step_id`,
        FROM steps 
        INNER JOIN players ON (players.player_step=step_id AND players.player_user=1)
    ) 
    AS t ON t.step_id=steps.step_id
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT 
            `step_tickets`, 
            `step_game`, 
            `step_id` 
        FROM steps 
        WHERE `step_num`=1 
    ) 
    AS d ON d.step_id=steps.step_id
    GROUP BY step_id
) 
AS p ON p.step_game=games.game_id
WHERE game_id=1
```

Comment: FYI, `IF(t.step_tickets IS NULL, d.step_tickets, t.step_tickets)` can be simplified to `IFNULL(t.step_tickets, d.step_tickets)`

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your tip, but it does not change the result

Comment: I never said it would. It was just a suggestion for how to make the code clearer.

Comment: @Barmar You're right and thanks again for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want one row from `steps`.  This row should match the game.  And, if possible, also match the user.  If there is no user, then you can return it.

If so:

```
select s.*
from steps s left join
     players p
     on p.player_step = s.step_id
where s.step_game = $game and
      (p.user_id = $user or p.user_id is null)
order by (p.user_id is not null) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: You are a genius :) Perfect